# Is there a way to optionally control creation of child elements in *ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

I have an array I use to generate elements in a form template. To simplify, let's say the array has 2 entries. Depending on the value in a variable, I'd like either to have one `<div>` with two `<label>` elements in the form, or two `<div>`'s each with one `<label>` element. (I'm trying to make a flexible form, where the user can specify how many columns he/she wants).

If I optionally create the `<div>` using an `*ngIf` statement, then when the `*ngIf` expression is false, the entire contents of the `<div>` DOM will be erased, which is not what I want.

Of course, one approach would be to re-configure the array to be either one or two dimensions based on the variable (one dimension with two entries, or two dimensions with one entry), but this would add significant complexity to the code, so I'm wondering if Angular offers a simpler solution at the template level that will achieve what I'm aiming for.

I want the output HTML to be either(1):

```
<div>
  <label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
</div>
```

or(2) . . .

```
<div>
  <label>
  <label>
</div>
```

depending on whether `someFunc(i)` is true or false.

Currently what I have is:

```
  <div class="member-row" *ngFor="let subkey of allKeys; let i = index">
      <label class="member-row-label">{{subkey[1]}}:&nbsp;</label>
  </div>
```

which yields case (1) above.

Is there any way to add logic into the template to allow it to accommodate either case (1) or (2) without needing to rewire the structure of the array and other associated code? I'm hoping I overlooked something obvious!

Comment: What is value of `i` in `someFunc(i)`

Comment: i is the index in the *ngFor loop (i.e. the index of the underlying array used to generate the template elements).

Comment: in case `someFunc(0)`  is true and `someFunc(1)`  is false then what's the expected behaviour

Comment: Following my example above, if someFunc(0) is true then the HTML would be as in case 1 above, and if someFunc(1) is true, then the HTML would be as in case 2 above . . .

Comment: It's still confusing

Answer (score 0):

> If I optionally create the  using an *ngIf statement, then when the *ngIf expression is false, the entire contents of the  DOM will be erased, which is not what I want.

Not "erased", but never created in the first place. Depending on the condition under the *ngIf, one version or another of the template will be created. In the most quick-and-dirty version:

```
<div *ngIf="condition">
  <label>
</div>
<div *ngIf="condition">
  <label>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!condition">
  <label>
  <label>
</div>
```

Then, to make it neater, you could follow the *ngIf-else pattern (https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf). Or make a separate component out of the whole thing.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies, mbojko and @Pranav C Balan. I should've made the example clearer to emphasize that the second <label> is only generated in the next iteration of the *ngFor loop. As such, my gut is telling me that the only way to solve the problem is to re-dimension the underlying array, but it would be great if you (or anyone else) can prove me wrong on that!